# Missing data when submit with DateTime and editor template in MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

I'm new in MVC. I use editor template for create 3 textbox for day, month, year for datetime type.
Main View:

```
    @model mvc3date.Models.SomeDate
```

...

```
<html>
...
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    { ...
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.oneday, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.oneday)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.oneday)@**@
                </div>
            </div>
...}

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Editor Template:

```
@model DateTime?
...
    <td>@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd") : string.Empty)) </td>
    <td class="separator">/</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM") : string.Empty))</td>
    <td class="separator">/</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("yyyy") : string.Empty))</td>
```

My problem not done when I try to change editor template to:

```
    <td>@Html.TextBox("Day", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd") : string.Empty)) </td>
    <td class="separator">/</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("Month", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM") : string.Empty))</td>
    <td class="separator">/</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBox("Year", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("yyyy") : string.Empty))</td>
```

With new editor template, validation for model.oneday return true and can be submit this form. But when submit, the value of oneday is null! How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `EditorTemplate` is creating 3 textboxes with the name `oneday` When you submit the form, the `DefaultModelBinder` tries to set the value of `oneday` to the first value it sees (a 1 or 2 digit number) which of course fails (try setting `DateTime oneday = 7;` yourself). Even if by magic it did succeed, the other 2 values would be ignored anyway.

In the second `EditorTemplate` your controls have `name="Day"`,`name="Month"` and `name="Year"`. If you inspect `Response.Form` you will see these name/value pairs but since you model does not have any properties named `Day`, `Month` or `Year` then nothing is bound (they are just ignored).

In unclear why you would want to do this, especially as you cant use client side validation, but you either need

1. A view model with 3 properties, for `Day`, `Month` and `Year` so
   that you can strongly bind to the properties using html helpers. In
   the POST method you can then construct the date based on the 3
   properties.
2. Manually add the (unbound) html as you are doing in the second template, and
   write your own custom `ModelBinder` that reads the form data values
   and builds the date. An example is shown in [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for you help. But I can't use 3 properties in model. I had try example of your article but not success full. **cry** **sad**

Comment: Then your not following the example in the link correctly.

Comment: Yes, I not do step step. Thus, I fail. I will try step by step as you talk. Thanks.

Comment: And I have just seen your other question. First remove that incorrect `[Bind(Include="..")]` but more importantly, where have you defined that the `Create()` method should use your `DateAndTimeModelBinder`?

Comment: Oh, thanks @Step Muecke, but that old prolem have been fixed. Not only remove [Bind(Include="..")], i must replace return tday; by return date;.
Have a nice day (smile)

Comment: I must make three text box to input date and validate on client side, but model must be one type DateTime. I don't want do this but my teacher want (cry).

Comment: Ah ah, I forgot check green for your answer. Sorry, I'm new in stackoverflow.

Comment: OK, But I don't understand why you have a problem with creating view model containing properties for the Date and properties for the Day, Month and Year so you can strongly bind. Every view should have a specific view model containing the properties you need for editing

Comment: This is homework to training. So I must do that with hard way.